# How to bind a value in json object in vue js

Tags: json, vue.js, object, vuex

I'd used vuetify component to make todo app using vuejs with firebase DB.I want to bind title from json object. but I haven't idea to bind any particular value or attribute in from obeject

```html
<v-text-field
  v-model="title"
  outlined
  full-width
  label="Another input"
></v-text-field>
```

```js
todo: {
  id: this.id,
  title: "Welcome to vue js",
  date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
},
```

Comment: just do `v-model="todo.title"`

Answer (score 1):

you can use computed https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter
Something like this:

```js
computed: {
  title: {
    set: function(value){
      this.todo.title = value
    },
    get: function() {
      return this.todo.title
    }
  }
}
```

Then bind computed property with input

```html
<v-text-field
  v-model="title"
  outlined
  full-width
  label="Another input"
></v-text-field>
```

Comment: and if you wanted to bind a json to an element? where the json might be generated or dynamic and you're not sure you know the property name?